# How to replace letters of work with reference table column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to replace each letter of a column (nvarchar) with the letters defined earlier:

I got 2 tables : Data, EncodingReference

In data table I have a single column called Name with the data below:

| Name |
| --- |
| New |
| My |
| Beep |

In the EncodingReference table I have 2 columns

| SourceLetter | TargetLetter |
| --- | --- |
| N | E |
| B | M |

What I want to get is the following result set:

| Name |
| --- |
| EEW |
| My |
| Meep |

Basically I want to replace each letter with the target letter stored in another table.

Comment: If `Name` were `New Baby` would the output `Eew Maby`?

Comment: @JNevill yes, that is correct , there could be more than one word in the row.

Comment: Why would this example not be `Eew MaMy`? Or is your data perhaps a Case Sensitive collation?

Comment: @Stu I was assuming case sensitivity. It's not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly the following may serve your purpose using *translate*

```
select Translate(name, s, t) Name
from data d
cross apply (
  select String_Agg(sourceLetter,'')s, String_Agg(Targetletter,'')t
  from EncodingReference
)er;
```